# many to one Find(id) entity framework MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one to many relationship between to table `UserProfiles` and  `Companies` so in the `Details Action` Method i'm trying to get the `UserName` that have company from the `UserProfile` by the `UserId` to display the company with her owner by using the `Find(id)` Method but is not working.

[image]

The `Details Action` Method

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        var companys = db.Companys.Include(c => c.UserProfile.UserId);
        var company = companys.Find(id);
        if (company == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(company);
    }
```

so what I'm doing wrong please correct me and thanks for any help.

and this is my models Company

```
 public class Company
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Company Name")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is required")]
    [DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
    //[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string CompanyPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Address is required")]
    [DisplayName("Company Address")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    //must change in view(LINQ) to give only the manager user
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Manager Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Manager Name")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

}

and the `UserProfile` model

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UsersInRoles> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
    public Membership Membership { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companys { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }

}

}
```

Comment: What is the id that is being passed into Details? Is it a user id or company id?

Comment: the company id is being passed into Details

Comment: Find should work. The problem is with the Include line above. You don't need it.

Comment: i'm trying to get the `UserName` that have company from the `UserProfile` by the `UserId` to display the company with her owner

Comment: If you're trying to get the UserName, please update your question as right now it only mentions that you want the UserId.

Comment: db.Companys.Include(c => c.UserProfile).Where(c => c.UserProfile.UserId == id).ToList()

Comment: Could you show the model. Because you can access also the `Companies` object via the model `UserProfile`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        var companys = db.Companys.Where(x => x.CompanyID == id).ToList();
        if (companys == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(companys);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
var company = db.Companys.Include(c => c.UserProfile.UserId).Where(x=>x.Id == id);
```

or

```
var company = db.Companys.Include(c => c.UserProfile.UserId).First(x=>x.Id == id);
```

or

```
var company = (form c in db.Companys
              where c.Id == id
              select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
   {
    var companys = db.Companys.Include(c => c.UserProfile);
    var company = companys.Where(c=>c.UserId == id);
    if (company == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(company);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

update Company class like

```
public class Company
{
  //instead of UserId
  public int UserProfileId {get;set;}
  //instead of UserProfile
  public virtual UserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}   
}
```

and in the controller

```
var companys = db.Companys.Include(c => c.UserProfile);
```